# Single-threaded request-response type server architecture

Tags: architecture, server, client-server, async, rust

I'm writing an internet service in Rust that works more or less like an HTTP-server, just without the HTTP part, and strictly over UDP. I also have a requirement to build it like an old-school game of the 90s, because it supposedly produces code that is simpler to compose, maintain and debug than any other way. So I need to have an explicit main loop and some "game" (server) state structure.

The code looks something like this:

```rust
enum HandlerA {
  New(Message),
  Stage1(/* Stage1 stuff */),
  Stage2(/* ... */),
  Stage3(/* ... */),
  Ready(Message),
}

enum HandlerB {
  New(Message),
  /* Stages */
  Read(Message),
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct Server {
  incoming: Vec<Message>,
  handlers_a: Vec<HandlerA>,
  handlers_b: Vec<HandlerB>,
  outgoing: Vec<Message>,
}

fn main() {
  let server = Server::default();
  let socket = UdpSocket::bind(addr).unwrap();
  socket.set_nonblocking(true);
  loop {
    retrieve_messages(&socket, &mut server.incoming);
    dispatch_handlers(&mut server.incoming, &mut server.handlers_a, &mut server.handlers_b);
    advance_handlers(&mut server.handlers_a, &mut server.handlers_b);
    collect_responses(&mut server.handlers_a, &mut server.handlers_b, &mut server.outgoing);
    send_responses(&socket, &mut server.outgoing);
  }
}
```

It's probably suboptimal as it's single threaded, but since it will be running on a Linux system, I can spawn multiple instances of it matching the number of cores that all bind to the same port (setting [SO_REUSEADDR](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)). That the way the Linux kernel will function as a load balancer, or so I hope.

Another problem is the CPU usage if the loop is not throttled. I assume this can be solved by adding sleep to the main loop that adapts to the average load over some timespan. Threads should be the last resort.

I feel like using Rust's async/await infrastructure may be more readable in the long run, but it will also probably be much harder to debug (and will no longer look like a game), so I'm not going that way.

Is this a passable architecture for a request-response kind of server (ignoring the use of a raw UDP socket)? Can it be improved? Does it have some fatal flaw?

Comment: Is this going to be a single player game, so when you have multiple users, each one can be served by a different instance? Or do you expect multiple users connected to the same game instance?

Comment: The reason http servers are multi threaded is to prevent a single request from ddos-ing your server. Exclusive socket ownership is also necessary for security reasons. If you don't care about security, then you should be fine.

Comment: @Ccm it’s not uncommon to just start many processes, each single threaded. So a single request may block one of thousand processes and blocked processes take no cpu time. Also why you have server CPUs that focus on having tons of threads at not very high performance.

Comment: An ["actual" event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) is far more effective than a simple loop, in terms of server responsiveness. Consider using one from `tokio-core`